# Google eclipse java style: changing 2-space indentation to 4-space indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I got the Google java style from here:
https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

It seems like this style using 2-space indentation. But I want 4-space indentation. **I think** I found the line which controls the indentation:

`<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="2"/>`

Changed to:

`<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.continuation_indentation" value="4"/>`

And added to the [git formatter plugin](https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin).  Ran the `formatter:format` again, but nothing changed (still 2-space indentation).

Am I changing the correct line in the configuration file? If not, what is the correct line describing the indentation?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the tabulation.size worked for me.

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="4"/>
```